# Python: No performance improvement with multiprocessing.Pool() using apply_async

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, multiprocessing, pool

i am extracting and decoding a large trace file with a few million messages. The message data is decoded using a .dbc file and the cantools package.

Because of the size the list with messages has, i tried to decode them parallel using the multiprocessing module.
As i am not able to make any perfomance boosts, using various methods implementing **multiprocessing.Queue()** and **multiprocessing.Manager()** i came after some research to this implementation using the **multiprocessing.Pool()** class.

From my understanding this should be the most suitable solution. But this as well even slows the process of decoding down and i fail to understand why.

**Minimal Code for decoding the messages using Pool()**:

```
import cantools
import multiprocessing as mp

CORES_USED = 4


def decode_multiplepool(self, msgs):
    """ tries to decode multiple msgs on every can decoding interface """

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=CORES_USED)
    starts = [int(core * len(msgs) / CORES_USED) if core else 0 for core in range(CORES_USED)]
    ends = [int((core+1) * len(msgs) / CORES_USED) for core in range(CORES_USED)]
    results = [pool.apply_async(self._aux_decode_list, args=(msgs[starts[core]:ends[core]])) for core in range(CORES_USED)]

    msgs = []
    for elem in results:
        msgs.extend(elem.get())
    return msgs
    
def _aux_decode_list(self, msgs, mask):
    """ helper function for decoding messages in different processes 
    
    for msg in msgs:
        msg.msg_data = self.decode_msg(msg.msg_id, msg.raw_data)
    return msgs
```

My implementation splits the original big list of messages into smaller pieces, decodes every piece in another process and merges the list back together.

**For comparison, this the very simple implementation by iterating over the full list:**

```
def decode_msgs_serial(self, msgs):
    """ tries to decode multiple msgs on every can decoding interface """
        
    for msg in msgs:
        msg.msg_data = self.decode_msg(msg.msg_id, msg.raw_data)
    return msgs
```

**As a result, the serial implementation works faster.** Tried on 5 a little different sized Trace files. All times are in seconds.

```
C:\workspace\Trace_Decoder>main.py

Modes.ORIGINAL - this took 55.905028104782104
Modes.ORIGINAL - this took 53.10664439201355
Modes.ORIGINAL - this took 69.6441662311554
Modes.ORIGINAL - this took 55.500239849090576
Modes.ORIGINAL - this took 67.86816716194153

Modes.MULTICORE - this took 81.50722122192383
Modes.MULTICORE - this took 82.05325841903687
Modes.MULTICORE - this took 74.6193528175354
Modes.MULTICORE - this took 65.481980323791504
Modes.MULTICORE - this took 70.18386173248291
```

Any help is very much appreciated, as i think this is very interesting subject to learn from!